# Why is my vue.config.js file not working?

Tags: vue.js

I want to deploy my app and for that i need the vue.config.js file for a target url.
But everything i place in this file (i had to create it myself), is not working. not the outputDir for the build or the proxy inside devServer.
Has anyone had this same issue and got is fixed? Please help me

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../server/public'),
    devServer: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
           target: 'http://localhost:8081/'
        }
     }
    }
  };
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "restrace",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "restrace app",
  "author": "Marcel Beks <mbeks1@avans.nl>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit test/e2e/specs",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-google-autocomplete": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "inject-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.3.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.2",
    "mocha": "^3.5.3",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.12",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "selenium-server": "^3.0.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "sinon": "^4.0.0",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Well, I expected to see the very mentioned `vue.config.js` file when I got to the page.

Comment: Sorry, i included it now

Comment: Are you using a vue project generated by the vue cli 3? Do the commands in your `package.json` include `vue-cli-service`?

Comment: No i cant find it in my package.json

Comment: Could you share your package json file?

Comment: i added the package.json file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using old [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/v2#vue-cli--) and scaffolded your project using `vue init webpack <project-name>`.

Since it all evolved into [vue cli 3](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/), old vue-cli is deprecated and we are now using @vue/cli and `vue create <project-name>` for scaffolding out projects.

It's perfectly fine for you to use the old way(and I still do sometimes), and vue.config.js is the global configuration file for your project **when** you are using @vue/cli. Check more about it [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js).

For webpack configurations when using vue-cli and in projects scaffolded using `npm init` command, check the **/build** directory in the root of the project folder.

Answer (score 2):

The `vue.config.js` file is only used when using the `vue-cli-service`. If you are using Vue CLI 3 or higher, it should create a project without any visible webpack configuration. Instead, the `vue-cli-service` will look for a `vue.config.js` file to configure your build.

In your case you are using an older version. Your webpack configuration is inside the `build` folder, as hinted by your package.json. Your build folder should contain three files, namely `webpack.base.conf.js`, `webpack.dev.conf.js` and `webpack.prod.conf.js`. The base file is used for both environments. The dev file is used for your dev server (when you run `npm run dev`). The prod file is used for production (when you build your application using `npm run build`). Modify these files to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: I now created the project with the vue cli service, and copied my vue files over. i got everything running again, except the vue.config.js file is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Look like that you created the 'restrace' project via the command.

```sh
vue init webpack restrace
```

Might you take a try to use the following command for creating your 'restrace' project?

```sh
vue create restrace
```

And then the `vue.config.js` file will be working.

Answer (score 1):

This may not have been the OP's issue, but in case someone else stumbles onto this SO question...

In the Vue-CLI v.4.5.13 (with `@vue/cli-service@4.3.1`), there is a [bug documented here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5442) that causes a **silent failure** if there is an invalid `require(...)` in your `vue.config.js`. When there's a bad `require(...)`, your `vue.config.js` file gets completely **ignored**!

To perform a sanity check, at a command prompt you can run the `vue inspect` (or `vue inspect --mode production`) command to see if that reports any errors. You can play with your `vue.config.js` file, perhaps removing all `require(...)` statements, or intentionally adding invalid ones, to see the effect.